# Colours change as bouncing an object off wall

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to animate a happy face to change colour as it hits the walls. Currently, I have the variables set and a loop for the happy face to change colour as it hits the wall. Its right now saying there is error with the code:

> ```py
> shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_colour())
>    NameError: name 'random_colour' is not defined
> ```

```
color = GREEN 
color2 = BLUE
color3 = RED

# funtion to draw a the "happy face"
# it has 4 parameters passed to it xPos, yPos, radius, and colour
# notice all the shapes are drawn "relative" to the xPos and yPos and the radius
def drawHappy(xPos,yPos,r,colour):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,colour,(xPos,yPos),r,1)
    eyeRadius = int(1/6*r)
    eyeX = int(xPos-1/3*r)
    eyeY = int(yPos- 1/3*r)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,colour,(eyeX,eyeY),eyeRadius,1)
    eyeX = int(xPos + 1/3*r)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,colour,(eyeX,eyeY),eyeRadius,1)
    wMouth = 1.5*r
    xMouth = xPos - 3/4*r
    yMouth = yPos - 3/4*r
    pygame.draw.arc(screen,colour,(xMouth,yMouth,wMouth,wMouth),math.pi,2*math.pi,1)

def random_color():
    random_number = random.randint(1,3)
    if random_number == 1:
            return GREEN
    elif random_number ==2:
            return BLUE
    else:
            return RED

# set up clock to control frames per second
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 120

xPos = 0
yPos = 0
dx = 0
dy = 0

xPos2 = 0
yPos2 = 0
dx2 = 0
dy2 = 0

xPos3 = 0
yPos3 = 0 
dx3 = 0
dy3 = 0

xPos = xPos + dx
yPos = yPos + dy

yPos2 = yPos2 + dy2
xPos2 = xPos2 + dx2

yPos3 = yPos3 + dy3
xPos3 = xPos3 + dx3


# set main loop to True so it will run
main = True
# main loop
while main:
    for event in pygame.event.get():  # check for any events (i.e key press, mouse click etc.)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # check to see if it was "x" at top right of screen
            main = False # set the "main" variable to False to exit while loop

        if xPos >= 750:
            dxPos = -abs(dx)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_colour())
            color = random_color()
        elif xPos <=50:
            dx = abs(dx)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_colour())
            color = random_color()

        if yPos <= 50:
            dy = abs(dy)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_colour())
            color = random_color()
        elif yPos >=550:
            dyPos = -abs(dyPos)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_colour())
            color = random_color()

        if xPos2 >= 775:
            dx = -abs(dx)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_colour())
            color2 = random_color()
        elif xPos2 <= 25:
            dx = abs(dx)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_colour())
            color2 = random_color()

        if   yPos2 <= 25:
            dy = abs(dy)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_colour())
            color2 = random_color()
        elif yPos2 >= 575:
            dy = -abs(dy)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_colour())
            color2 = random_color()

        if   xPos3 >=700:
            dx = -abs(dx)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_colour())
            color3 = random_color()
        elif xPos3 <= 100:
            dx = abs(dx)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_colour())
            color3 = random_color()

        if   yPos3 <= 100:
            dy = abs(dy)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_colour())
            color3 = random_color()
        elif yPos3 >= 500:
            dy = -abs(dy)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_colour())
            color3 = random_color()


    clock.tick(FPS)
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # "call" the function "drawHappy()" to draw the happy face
    # this is where we would normally do a pygame.draw or a screen.blit()
    # we are "passing" the function 4 values to use(x,y,radius, colour)
    # it will use these to know where to draw the happy face
    drawHappy(300,300,200,RED)

    pygame.display.flip()

# quit pygame and exit the program (i.e. close everything down)
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: *"now saying [...]  'random_colour' is not defined"* - Yes of course, because the function `random_colour()` is not defined in that code.

Answer (score 1):

You created a function `random_color` but you are calling the function `random_colour` when using it. A simple typo.